# spatie/laravel-analytics performQuery error

Tags: php, laravel, analytics

I use spatie laravel google analytics with no error but 
when I use:

```
 $analyticsData = Analytics::performQuery($per,'ga:sessions',$dimen);
```

I get this error:

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

All my code is:

```
   $startDate = Carbon::now()->subYear();
   $endDate = Carbon::now();

   $per=Period::create($startDate, $endDate);
   $dimen=['dimensions' => 'ga:browser'];

   $analyticsData = Analytics::performQuery($per,'ga:sessions',$dimen);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this, just you have to change your metrics and dimensions as per your requirement.

```
$days = 30;

$users = Analytics::performQuery(Period::days($days),'ga:users',['dimensions'=>'ga:campaign,ga:source,ga:medium']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify last perimeter as an array

```
Analytics::performQuery($period,'ga:sessions',['dimensions' => $dimen]);
```