# htmlspecialchars() expects parameter spatie/laravel-analytics

Tags: php, laravel

My controller.

```
public function showMonthlyReport($site_id, $report_id){

$reports = Report::where('report_id', $report_id)->firstOrFail();

$days = 30;

$sessions = Analytics::performQuery(Period::days($days),'ga:sessions',['dimensions' => 'ga:browser']);

$users = Analytics::performQuery(Period::days($days),
        'ga:users',
        [
            'metrics' => 'ga:pageviews',
            'dimensions' => 'ga:pageTitle',
            'sort' => '-ga:pageviews',
            'max-results' => 10,
        ]);

 return view('records', compact('site_id', 'report_id', 'reports', 'sessions', 'users'));

}
```

blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Hello Analytics</title>


<h1>Hello Analytics</h1>

{{!! $sessions !!}}

{{!! $users !!}}

</body>
</html>
```

My dd($session);

```
Google_Service_Analytics_GaData {#255 ▼
#collection_key: "rows"
#columnHeadersType: "Google_Service_Analytics_GaDataColumnHeaders"
#columnHeadersDataType: "array"
+containsSampledData: false
+dataLastRefreshed: null
#dataTableType: "Google_Service_Analytics_GaDataDataTable"
#dataTableDataType: ""
+id: "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:&dimensions=ga:browser&metrics=ga:sessions&start-date=2018-08-07&end-date=2018-09-06"
+itemsPerPage: 1000
+kind: "analytics#gaData"
+nextLink: null
+previousLink: null
#profileInfoType: "Google_Service_Analytics_GaDataProfileInfo"
#profileInfoDataType: ""
#queryType: "Google_Service_Analytics_GaDataQuery"
#queryDataType: ""
+rows: array:19 [▶]
+sampleSize: null
+sampleSpace: null
+selfLink: "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga&dimensions=ga:browser&metrics=ga:sessions&start-date=2018-08-07&end-date=2018-09-06"
+totalResults: 19
+totalsForAllResults: array:1 [▼
"ga:sessions" => "2772"
]
#internal_gapi_mappings: []
#modelData: []
#processed: []
+"query": Google_Service_Analytics_GaDataQuery {#256 ▼
#collection_key: "sort"
#internal_gapi_mappings: array:4 [▼
  "endDate" => "end-date"
  "maxResults" => "max-results"
  "startDate" => "start-date"
  "startIndex" => "start-index"
]
+dimensions: "ga:browser"
+endDate: "2018-09-06"
+filters: null
+ids: "ga:
+maxResults: 1000
+metrics: array:1 [▼
  0 => "ga:sessions"
]
+samplingLevel: null
+segment: null
+sort: null
+startDate: "2018-08-07"
+startIndex: 1
#modelData: array:4 [▼
  "start-date" => "2018-08-07"
  "end-date" => "2018-09-06"
  "start-index" => 1
  "max-results" => 1000
]
#processed: []
}
+"profileInfo": Google_Service_Analytics_GaDataProfileInfo {#257 ▼
+accountId: "593074"
+internalWebPropertyId: "11344328"
+profileId: 
+profileName: 
+tableId: 
+webPropertyId: 
#internal_gapi_mappings: []
#modelData: []
#processed: []
}
+"columnHeaders": array:2 [▼
0 => Google_Service_Analytics_GaDataColumnHeaders {#258 ▼
  +columnType: "DIMENSION"
  +dataType: "STRING"
  +name: "ga:browser"
  #internal_gapi_mappings: []
  #modelData: []
  #processed: []
}
1 => Google_Service_Analytics_GaDataColumnHeaders {#259 ▼
  +columnType: "METRIC"
  +dataType: "INTEGER"
  +name: "ga:sessions"
  #internal_gapi_mappings: []
  #modelData: []
  #processed: []
  }
 ] 
}
```

Have need to delete those View id: any the websites that i'm currently gathering data. You can check above my `dd($session);

Do you have any idea how to fix this? Like I follow all the rules on spatie/laravel-analytics but it gives me those errors `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`

Been tried some of this code but I got the same error [spatie/laravel-analytics performQuery error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44739481/spatie-laravel-analytics-performquery-error)

Comment: The error comes from the `sessions` query or the `users` one?

Comment: @DavidWinder no idea `…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php560` only giving me this.

Comment: This error is likely coming from your `view` file (`records.blade.php`); Can you post that file? Using `{{ }}` (and maybe `{!! !!}`?) blade directives calls `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: @TimLewis updated. And tried {{!! !!}} and gets this error `"Object of class Google_Service_Analytics_GaData could not be converted to string`

Comment: Sorry, wasn't suggesting to use `{!! !!}`, was a note that it might use `htmlspecialchars()`, and you've got an extra `{}` (`{{!! !!}}` vs `{!! !!}`) there anyway. Stick with `{{ }}`. In your controller, do a `dd($sessions)` and see what it contains. I'm not too familiar with `Analytics::` usage, but I thought it returned a `string`

Comment: @JagadeshaNH do i need to put that on my view file?

Comment: `performQuery` return array|null as said here https://phpdoc.hotexamples.com/class/spatie.analytics/Analytics#method-performQuery and here: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-analytics/blob/a939043be66c1cc1976a8ec9b90b7157f8bdb682/src/AnalyticsClient.php

Comment: @TimLewis when I dd($sessions) I got Google_Service_Analytics_GaData {#255 ▶}

Comment: Yeah, so it's not a `string` and won't work with `{{ $sessions }}`. Again, not too familiar with `Analytics`, but some of the other comments seem to suggest not using `performQuery`, or, if you do, might need to do something `{{ $sessions->result }}` (or similar)

Comment: @ChristianGallarmin htmlspecialchars()  is a PHP function that accepts just a string, so when you use {{ }} make sure your passing string not anything else like object or something.

Comment: @JagadeshaNH so do i need to make a foreach inside my blade?

Comment: @ChristianGallarmin yes just dd and check what is the type and accordingly you have to change your code

Comment: @JagadeshaNH my dd($session) was above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looking at your dd $sessions is an object so just try

```
{{ $sessions->id }}
```

this will print without any error

```
foreach($sessions->toArray() as $key => $value )
{
    echo $key;
}
```

Comment: @JagadeshaNH yeah it didn't print any error. But its not the right answer.

Comment: @ChristianGallarmin Its an object so you need to print each values seperately or loop through the object keys and do it

Comment: the foreach you've used is like echo on my view file. @JagadeshaNH

Comment: Call to undefined method Google_Service_Analytics_GaData::toArray()

Comment: yes collection or Item on $sessions first before calling ->toArray(); https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-toarray

Comment: how can I able to put that on my $sessions on my controller? like I'am so confused.